# Java Exception: unknown protocol: udp

Tags: java, url, exception, udp, malformedurlexception

I am trying to run a basic java program as part of reverse engineering an application. 
I am getting

> java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: udp

exception while running following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = new URL("udp://xxx.xxxx.com:1234/");
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So.... what is the question? The error tells you explicitly what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem here is really that udp is not a protocol; it's a transport, like tcp. You can't use a `tcp://host:port/` URL either.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

You are using a version of the Java Developer Kit (JDK) that was released prior to JDK 1.4.

Comment: when i tried i got that error bcoz of jdk only hw just read topic of above link