# UDP stream not playing on ExoPlayer

Tags: java, android, udp, exoplayer

I am new in Exoplayer udp streaming. I already done some working on HTTP live streaming but not udp. Now trying to play a udp stream on exoplayer, googled a lot, but no luck.

Please have a look on the following logcat.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
04-03 21:33:45.376 31547-31827/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to udp://@x.x.x.x:xxxx
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:194)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:137)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:692)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
     Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: udp
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:596)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:486)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:435)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:341)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:192)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:137) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:692) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:315) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762) 
04-03 21:33:45.377 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onPlayerError...
04-03 21:33:45.378 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onTimelineChanged...
    Listener-onLoadingChanged...isLoading:false
04-03 21:33:45.379 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onPlayerStateChanged...1
04-03 21:33:45.395 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onPlayerStateChanged...2
04-03 21:33:45.396 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onTimelineChanged...
    Listener-onLoadingChanged...isLoading:true
04-03 21:33:48.406 31547-31827/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to udp://@224.2.2.1:3000
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:194)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:137)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:692)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
     Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: udp
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:596)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:486)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:435)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:341)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:192)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:137) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:692) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:315) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762) 
04-03 21:33:48.419 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onPlayerError...
04-03 21:33:48.421 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onTimelineChanged...
04-03 21:33:48.422 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onLoadingChanged...isLoading:false
04-03 21:33:48.423 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onPlayerStateChanged...1
04-03 21:33:48.440 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onPlayerStateChanged...2
04-03 21:33:48.441 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onTimelineChanged...
04-03 21:33:48.442 31547-31547/com.chernowii.udp_stream_android V/ExoPlayer GP Demo: Listener-onLoadingChanged...isLoading:true
```

Comment: Without knowing what kind of URL you passed to receive a java.net.MalformedURLException, it's extremely difficult to assist you. I'm going to take a stab and say you passed a URL incorrectly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437232/java-exception-unknown-protocol-udp)

Comment: I am using udp://@xxxx:xx

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create exactly Media Source for Exo like

```
val myDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, null, { -> UdpDataSource(this, 2000, 20000) })
// Extractor factory & media source
val extractorsFactory = DefaultExtractorsFactory()
val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource(uri, myDataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null)
player?.prepare(mediaSource, true, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same issue, even by using this code:

```
aExtractorMediaSourceFactory := TJExtractorMediaSource_Factory.JavaClass.init(fDataSourceFactory);
aVideoSource := aExtractorMediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(StrToJURI(aDataSource));
aExtractorMediaSourceFactory := nil;
```

It seems to be that the HTTP source class is always used and not the default data source.